# Initial page numbers wrong

Tags: margins, page-numbering

I am going crazy over the page numbers in my thesis. I have included the relevant part of my document below.

I have two problems:

- The dedication is numbered **ii.** which is good, but the abstract is not numbered, the table of contents resets to **i.**, and the second page of the ToC is numbered **1**.
- Page numbers for roman style and "new chapter" pages appear bottom-center instead of top-right, which is fine with me, but they fall below the allowed margin of 1 inch.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{verbatim,enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\setlength{\topmargin}{0 in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.25 in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5 in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6 in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5 in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.25 in}
\newcommand{\singlespaced}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalfont}
\newcommand{\doublespaced}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\normalfont}

\doublespaced

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{titlepage}
\include{dedication}
\include{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{myheadings} \markright{}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Put a `\clearpage` before every `\pagenumbering`. `\pagenumbering` changes the page number of the current page and not the next one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get three times a page 1 in the front matter: in the `report` class the `titlepage` environment which is used also by `abstract` resets the page number to 1.

I suggest you to use the `book` class with its `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands, with `\chapter{\abstractname}` for the abstract in the front matter.

However also the `report` class can be used, after patching the relevant commands; I show only the important parts, add the rest to suit. It's probably better to `\usepackage[<options>]{geometry}` for setting the page parameters and `\usepackage{setspace}` for the interline spacing.

Remember the `\clearpage` command before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%%% PATCHES %%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Patch `titlepage` not to reset the page number
\patchcmd{\titlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endtitlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}{}{}

% Patch `abstract` so that it shows the page number
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\titlepage}{\titlepage\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%% END PATCHES %%%

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
abc
\end{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
dddd
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage %%%%% <---- IMPORTANT
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{myheadings} \markright{}
\chapter{A}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The counter is working properly now, but how do I make a page number appear on the abstract page?

Comment: @Nick I've added the code.

Comment: I fully agree with @egreg answer, but also remember that '\pagenumbering` reset the `page` counter to 1. If you want to avoid this, you can replace `pagenumbering{arabic}` by `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}`